# From where does maven picks up java version if my java home is empty

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

From where does Maven pick up the Java version if my `$JAVA_HOME` is empty? I am using OSX. I have just specified in pom.xml like this:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: `mvn -version` prints the path to the java installation

Comment: that prints java 11 but my jar is building with version 8

Comment: Are you sure that it's building *with* Java 8? You just specified that you want to build *for* Java 8.

Comment: yes its building with java 8 but how?maven version shows me 11

Comment: @deadlybeast Is it clear to you that you can build for Java 8 with a JDK 11? The installed JDK and the Java version you specify in Maven need not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into your Project Structure in IntellJ using

⌘ + ;

[image]

**Edit**
Most likely you're using maven bundled with IntelliJ which I believe is aware of the java version that IDE sets. You can check that by going to preference.

⌘ + ,

[image]
Also `buildpath` is used during compile time to find your source files, SDK and external libraries/dependencies

You'll also hear the term `classpath` which is used during runtime to find the compiled class files and other resources.

Comment: yes it is like this but how does maven knows which one to refer m using below command -: mvn clean install to build jar

Answer (score 0):

Maven draws your java version from your projects build path. 
[Image of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYogh.png)
This allows you to pick which java version using the library searches. 
First, maven puts things in the build path that it needs to execute the code in run time. These things include things like libraries and dependencies. You can find it by right-clicking, scrolling down to build path, and then clicking, "Build path configurations" or something like that.

Comment: sorry i am naive but what does project build path here mean .i have seen in other answers where it is wriiten that it picks from java_home.What is the difference between these two.please help!